# Will multiple BuddyPress groups slow down a site?

Tags: buddypress, performance

I'm looking into creating a support forum where each product has it's own mini support forum. I was told that BuddyPress could work well for this, but I'm wondering how that scales for a site that has hundreds or thousands of active products. Any idea what kind of impact that would have on site speed and performance?

**Edit:**

To make the reason for this more clear, the site is a marketplace, where each product can have a different seller. That's why I'm not looking (nor do I care for) a central support system. Each individual seller is responsible for their own support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily scale a site to have tens or hundreds of thousands of BuddyPress groups. Groups themselves are negligible in terms of storage. When you start getting lots of forum content etc in the groups, you'll have to worry about scaling, but you'd have to do that whether you were using BP as a wrapper or not.

Comment: Thanks so much, that is exactly the answer I was looking for! Are there any specific thresholds (pageviews, posts, etc) at which you'd start to optimize BuddyPress beyond the standard plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's just me, but why would you want to have a separate support forum for each product?  What about just using bbpress and setting up a general support forum for each category and use tags to keep track of the different products?  Either way, you want to make sure that there is a central point to keep track of all the questions asked.  BuddyPress is more of a social addon for WP than a support system.

Comment: It's a marketplace where the products have different sellers, which is the reason for a different forum for each product. So, there's no need for them to be kept track of in a central location. Any idea what kind of performance impact a setup like that would have?

Comment: I'm not really sure what kind of performance issues you would run up against.  There are some pretty big sites out there that run BuddyPress that you can check out and ping the webmasters of those sites.  I know Boone Gorges runs a pretty big site and is a great developer for Buddypress.  http://profiles.wordpress.org/boonebgorges/